# Is my OS installed onto my SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, operating-systems

I ordered a new laptop that came with a 500 GB HDD, so I added a 128 GB SSD. I kind of assumed they would install the OS onto the SSD since in my experience that has been the norm. I'm pretty sure they didn't, but I'm confused. I'm running Windows 8 so in 'This PC' it shows that I have 4 drives:

1. OS (`C:`)
   337 GB free of 372 GB
2. Data (`D:`)
   500 GB free of 500 GB
3. Dvd drive (`E:`)
4. Samsung SSD (`F:`)
   117 GB free of 119 GB

So storage-wise it seems like the OS is on the `C:` drive, but I'm confused because it seems like I have three hard drives.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, your Windows is installed on the HDD. It can't be on SSD, because only 2 GB are used and Windows installation takes more than that.

Right-click **My Computer** and choose **Manage**. Then go to **Disk Management**. You will see the list of hard drives and the partitions on each.

The partition with the **System** flag is the partition on which Windows is installed. Look then to see if it is on SSD.

[image]

Comment: Follow this advice.

Comment: Thanks yeah from here I see that the OS(C:) is in disc 1 along with Data(D:)

Comment: The SSD is in disc 0, if I uninstall windows from hdd and install windows to ssd will it work? Or do I also need to switch their positions inside the laptop?

Comment: @Kyle If you haven't activated Windows yet, yes, you can reinstall it on SSD. If it is activated, I believe (I'm not sure) that you can't activate it on another drive (It takes that as trying to install on another PC).

Comment: Oh no... that sucks =( i am so sad

Comment: @Cornelius Sure you can, it works just fine. It may trigger a reactivation but that should pass without issue.

Comment: The easiest way would be for you to disconnect the other drives while you are uninstalling window

Comment: @Cornelius Activation should not be a problem. I have yet to find a non-pirated copy of Windows that could not be activated. If you do it too often it might require you to call Microsoft and confirm (sometimes only to a machine) that you are only using one copy at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have 1 HDD of 1TB a DVD drive and an SSD drive.

The SSD has only 2 gig in use and on top of that, the OS is usually always installed on the C drive, which is not your SSD in your case.

And no, a store will not install an OS to the SSD unless you tell them to because the OS is already preinstalled. So they only unpack the box, open up the laptop, put in the SSD, screw it back together, put it in the box. No installation or anything done by the shop.